# Validate multiple schemas against a single Marshaller in spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-integration

In the below scenario, I have a marshaller that picks one object & validate against an xsd. I need to map this Request object to multiple xsds within one marshaller.

```
  <bean id="jaxbMarshallerForCOTRequestObject" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.fidintl.retail.myProject.model.th.Request</value>
            </list>
        </property>
       <property name="schema" value="classpath:internal/test1.xsd"></property>
       <property name="validationEventHandler" ref="ceFeedXmlValidationEventHandlerService"></property>
        <property name="marshallerProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="jaxb.encoding">
                    <value>ISO-8859-1</value>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Can somebody provide how?
I tried using `<schemas>` tag but it didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in java instead of xml using the method [setSchemas](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.html#setSchemas-org.springframework.core.io.Resource...-) of Jaxb2Marshaller and it works fine for me.

```
Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
jaxb2Marshaller.setPackagesToScan(""); //mention packages here
ClassPathResource xsdONE = new ClassPathResource(""); //path to first xsd
ClassPathResource xsdTWO = new ClassPathResource(""); //path to second xsd
jaxb2Marshaller.setSchemaLanguage(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
jaxb2Marshaller.setSchemas(xsdONE, xsdTWO);
jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();
```

---

P.S.
I know it is an old post, but I was searching for the answer some time back and stumbled upon this post. I was able to find the answer after googling a bit and then trying it out so thought it might help someone looking for an answer.